# When I load Unity5 application on android phono. It is not working. ERROR : Unfortunatly(gameName) has stopped

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

This is the log file.

09-01 19:25:10.588: E/Unity(4398): Unable to find main
09-01 19:25:10.628: E/art(4398): No implementation found for void com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRestartActivityIndicator() (tried Java_com_unity3d_player_UnityPlayer_nativeRestartActivityIndicator and Java_com_unity3d_player_UnityPlayer_nativeRestartActivityIndicator__)
09-01 19:25:10.630: E/AndroidRuntime(4398): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-01 19:25:10.630: E/AndroidRuntime(4398): java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]

I have google it but unable to find any suitable answere.
Thank you so much for answering.

Comment: How is Player Settings > Target Architecture configured? And on which Androd phone model are you trying to run the application?

Comment: @jeanLuc thank you so much for reply. Thanks It worked.
I did 2 things
1.Installed android studio with sdk tools.
 2. change  in player setting from external to force internal.

and It worked.I was very frustrated but now I am happy . Thanks a lot.